# How to implement QLCDNumbers with PyQt?

Tags: python, pyqt

By designing a GUI for my python script which works with PySerial for implementing some serial interface functions I want to have shown up some parameters reading out a source.
So this GUI for example has to show the actual voltage which is represented by the parameter volt_act.
I thought that I can connect the QLCDNumber lcdVoltage with the following code:

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("selfVoltage"), self.lcdVoltage, QtCore.SLOT("display(int)"))
```

And at the point I want to read the voltage I emit the parameter:

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("selfVoltage"), volt_act)
```

But that doesn't work. How can I correctly implement a QLCDNumber where the parameter is updated in real-time when I emit it?

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/old_style_signals_slots.html#short-circuit-signals):

> Short-circuit signals do not have a list of arguments or the
>   surrounding parentheses.
>
> Short-circuit signals may only be connected to slots that have been
>   implemented in Python. They cannot be connected to Qt slots or the
>   Python callables that wrap Qt slots.

You need to declare the variable type explicitly, if you intend to use Qt slots:

```
self.connect(self, QtCore.SIGNAL("selfVoltage(int)"), self.lcdVoltage, QtCore.SLOT("display(int)"))
```

and

```
self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL("selfVoltage(int)"), volt_act)
```

But, I'd really suggest you to use the [new style signals](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html).

First, you'd define a signal as class variable:

```
voltage = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
```

then connect it:

```
self.voltage.connect(self.lcdVoltage.display)
```

and finally, you'd emit:

```
self.voltage.emit(volt_act)
```